# Handle multiple sockets in a Vue project

Tags: node.js, sockets, vue.js

Right now I have a Vue frontend that interacts with a single socket, using Vue-native-socket. 
I need my app to listen to more than one socket, although on the documentation page of Vue-native-socket there is no information on how to implement that.

Is there any way to do this? Not necessarily with this library, I don't mind rewriting the code with another library, as long as it works.

Answer (score -1):

This could be as simple as just connecting two sockets and setting up their respective listeners. From a quick glance, most of what `vue-native-socket` accomplishes (in the context of the question) can be achieved using a `vuex` store as well, or writing your own plugin, or both!

Here's a simple solution:

#### store.js

```
const state = {
  signalSocket: undefined,
  dataSocket: undefined
}

const getters = {
  signalSocket: state => state.signalSocket,
  dataSocket: state => state.dataSocket,
}

const mutations = {
  signalSocket (state, v) {
    state.signalSocket = v
  },
  dataSocket (state, v) {
    state.dataSocket = v
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
})
```

#### App.vue

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    signalSocket: {
      get () { return this.$store.getters.signalSocket },
      set (v) { this.$store.commit('signalSocket', v) }
    },
    dataSocket: {
      get () { return this.$store.getters.dataSocket },
      set (v) { this.$store.commit('dataSocket', v) }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.signalSocket = new WebSocket('...')
    this.dataSocket = new WebSocket('...')
    ...
  }
}
</script>
```

If you want this variable to be available everywhere, much like `vue-socket-native`, you could add the following to your `main.js`

#### main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Store from './store'

Vue.use({
  install (Vue, options) {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$signalSocket', {
      get () {
        return store.getters.signalSocket
      },
      set (v) {
        return store.commit('signalSocket', v)
      }
    })
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$dataSocket', {
      get () {
        return store.getters.dataSocket
      },
      set (v) {
        return store.commit('dataSocket', v)
      }
    })
  }
})
```